# Yarbu Execution

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, software-installation

I am attempting to use a Project called [Yarbu](https://sourceforge.net/projects/yarbu/)

It appears to be exactly what I am looking for. However am having difficulty getting it to work.

I successfully completed the install by following the steps seen [here](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/softinstall.html).

After following those steps, I created a .conf file (found [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_ZZBZRCDoDmMmZxTy1QYkR1Qnc)) and placed it into /home/john/yarbu-1.4.8/etc/yarbu/conf/default

however still nothing happens when I execute the program.

I do not know how to proceed from here and I am fairly certain that its user error that is resulting from my unfamiliarity with linux.

What should I try next? 
Why does this program require "sudo" to execute?
Did I need to create the .conf file before I did "make install"?

Answer (score -1):

from that very same site:

> Because in this example we didn't change the behavior of the configure
>   script, the program was installed in the default place. In many cases
>   it's /usr/local/bin. If /usr/local/bin (or whatever place your program
>   was installed in) is already in your PATH, you can just run the
>   program by typing its name.

So unless you change the configure script behaviour the executable should be under /usr/local/bin

Comment: There are two files that appear in that location "yarbu" and "yarbu-engine". but how do I run them?

Comment: did you register for their forums? They have a section called help.
besides to run a command in linux/unix you do either full path /usr/local/bin/yarku or relative to where you are ./yarku (assuming you are inside /usr/local/bin)